# SQL Server Increment all digits in column by 1

Tags: sql-server

My existing column contains rows such as

```
`33583164+32702184+45119472+33583164+`33583164+32702184+45119472+33583164+
`6962818+11703027+22894651+34160658+4921875+6302341+47975195+4921875+32702184+21408615+`
```

I would like to increment each of these digits by 1 so that row 1 becomes

```
44694264+43813295+56230583+44694275+
```

Comment: How do you get from `33583164` to `44694264`, both end with 64, shouldn't one end in either 75 or 53?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`TRANSLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for this

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('33583164+32702184+45119472+33583164+33583164+32702184+45119472+33583164+ 6962818+11703027+22894651+34160658+4921875+6302341+47975195+4921875+32702184+21408615+', 
       '1234567890',
       '2345678901')
```

On versions before 2017 you can use a nested `REPLACE`. This needs to be ordered such that it is not replacing characters that were replacement characters in previous steps and so uses an intermediate character such as `~` so that it can distinguish between `1` that would have been created from the initial replace vs `1` in the original string (of course make sure you pick an intermediate character that you are happy will never appear in the original string).

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('0123456789'
, '0', '~')
, '9', '0')
, '8', '9')
, '7', '8')
, '6', '7')
, '5', '6')
, '4', '5')
, '3', '4')
, '2', '3')
, '1', '2')
, '~', '1')
```